# List all logins and roles assigned (including if none and only public)

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to come up with a query that can be used in SQL Server in order to list each user/group that has been granted a SQL Server Login and its associated role including if the user is only assigned the default public role.

I am very close to what I want however I am having issues consolidating the results into a single row instead of multiple rows.

Here is the query I am using currently using:

```
select 
    @@SERVERNAME,
    sl.name,
    isnull(DB_Roles.Roles,'public') 
from 
    syslogins sl 
left join
    (select 'sysadmin' as Roles
     union all 
     select 'securityadmin' 
     union all 
     select 'serveradmin' 
     union all 
     select 'setupadmin' 
     union all 
     select 'processadmin' 
     union all 
     select 'diskadmin' 
     union all 
     select 'dbcreator' 
     union all 
     select 'bulkadmin' 
     union all 
     select 'No serverRole' 
     union all
     select 'public') DB_Roles 
         on 
           case 
               when sl.sysadmin = 1 and DB_Roles.Roles = 'sysadmin' 
                   then 'sysadmin' 
               when sl.securityadmin = 1 and DB_Roles.Roles = 'securityadmin' 
                   then 'securityadmin'
               when sl.serveradmin = 1 and DB_Roles.Roles = 'serveradmin' 
                   then 'serveradmin' 
               when sl.setupadmin = 1 and DB_Roles.Roles = 'setupadmin' 
                   then 'setupadmin' 
               when sl.processadmin = 1 and DB_Roles.Roles = 'processadmin' 
                   then 'processadmin' 
               when sl.diskadmin = 1 and DB_Roles.Roles = 'diskadmin' 
                   then 'diskadmin' 
               when sl.dbcreator = 1 and DB_Roles.Roles = 'dbcreator' 
                   then 'dbcreator'  
               when sl.bulkadmin = 1 and DB_Roles.Roles = 'bulkadmin'  
                   then 'bulkadmin' 
               else null 
           end = DB_Roles.Roles
where 
    sl.name NOT IN ('##MS_SQLResourceSigningCertificate##', 
                    '##MS_SQLReplicationSigningCertificate##', 
                    '##MS_SQLAuthenticatorCertificate##', 
                    '##MS_PolicySigningCertificate##', 
                    '##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##', 
                    '##MS_SmoExtendedSigningCertificate##', 
                    '##MS_AgentSigningCertificate##', 
                    '##MS_PolicyTsqlExecutionLogin##', 
                    'NT Service\MSSQLSERVER', 
                    'NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT', 
                    'NT SERVICE\SQLWriter', 
                    'NT SERVICE\Winmgmt', 
                    'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 
                    'NT SERVICE\SQLTELEMETRY')
```

This outputs results that look like this:

```
WIN-H4H208120LQ sa  sysadmin
WIN-H4H208120LQ WIN-H4H208120LQ\user1   securityadmin
WIN-H4H208120LQ WIN-H4H208120LQ\Administrator   sysadmin
WIN-H4H208120LQ WIN-H4H208120LQ\Administrator   securityadmin
WIN-H4H208120LQ test123 sysadmin
WIN-H4H208120LQ test123 securityadmin
WIN-H4H208120LQ test123 serveradmin
WIN-H4H208120LQ test123 setupadmin
WIN-H4H208120LQ test123 processadmin
WIN-H4H208120LQ test123 diskadmin
WIN-H4H208120LQ test123 dbcreator
WIN-H4H208120LQ test123 bulkadmin
WIN-H4H208120LQ DOMAINNAME\user1 securityadmin
WIN-H4H208120LQ DOMAINNAME\Domain Admins    securityadmin
WIN-H4H208120LQ DOMAINNAME\Enterprise Admins    public
```

I would like to take every user for example test123 and consolidate into a single row that has comma separated the roles like this:

```
WIN-H4H208120LQ test123 sysadmin,securityadmin,serveradmin,setupadmin,processadmin,diskadmin,dbcreator,bulkadmin
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, instead, using the `sys.server_principals` and `sys.server_role_members` system objects rather than the SQL Server 2000 compatibility view [`syslogins`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syslogins-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

As for aggregating the strings, you can use `STRING_AGG`:

```sql
USE master;
GO

SELECT l.[name] AS LoginName,
       STRING_AGG(r.[name],N',')
FROM sys.server_principals l
     LEFT JOIN sys.server_role_members srm ON l.principal_id = srm.member_principal_id
     LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals r ON srm.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
WHERE l.[type] IN ('U','S','E','K','G','X','C') --Would probably be easier to do != 'R'...
  AND l.[name] NOT LIKE N'##%'
  AND l.[name] NOT LIKE N'NT SERVICE%'
  AND l.[name] NOT LIKE N'NT AUTH%'
GROUP BY l.[name];
```